# Is there a way to make mysql convert timezone automatically while fetching?

Tags: mysql, datetime, timezone

I have a table that has a column called `CTIME` which is of datetime type and it stores the GMT time.  I am setting my session's timezone like this:

```
set time_zone = '-7:00'
```

Now, if I fetch `CTIME` from the table, I still get the datetime in GMT.  Is there a way to make MySQL automatically do the timezone conversion while fetching?  I know I can use `CONVERT_TZ` function to explicitly convert the time zones.

Comment: You could create a view e.g. `CREATE VIEW view_localtime AS SELECT CONVERT_TZ(datetimecol, 'GMT', '-07:00') FROM yourtable`

Comment: what type is `CTIME`?

Comment: It is a datetime.